# LINQ query Joins

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

When i use the below code to retrieve information, it shows an error..

```
var mails = from m in entity.mailboxes
            join p in entity.ordinary_user_profile_info on m.from_id equals p.user_id
            select new MailList
            {
                mid = m.m_id,
                mfrom = m.**from_id,** // Error occours here
                mfomname = p.username,
                msubject = m.subject
            };
```

Error is:

> "int? mailbox.from_id "
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have declared `m_id` and `from_id` as int in DB  as well as in MailList class.

Comment: **(1)** Is `MailList.mfrom` an `int`?? **(2)** Edit your question and format your code with the "{}" button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var mails = from m in entity.mailboxes
            join p in entity.ordinary_user_profile_info on m.from_id equals p.user_id
            select new MailList
            {
                mid = m.m_id,
                mfrom = m.from_id ?? 0,
                mfomname = p.username,
                msubject = m.subject
            };
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing this should fix it.

so **int?** is a [Nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), you need to **either**

(1) Define `MailList.mfrom` as an `int`?   **OR**
(2) Convert from int? to int, like **below**:

```
var mails = from m in entity.mailboxes
            join p in entity.ordinary_user_profile_info on m.from_id equals p.user_id
            select new MailList
            {
                mid = m.m_id,
                **mfrom = m.from_id.HasValue ? m.from_id.Value : 0**
               //this is saying is, since the int is nullable, 
               //if it has a value, take it, or return 0
                mfomname = p.username,
                msubject = m.subject
            };
```

**Update**

---

After a little more research, seems like **@abatishchev** solution with the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is the correct way to go, according to msdn, and like **@Konstantin** on the comments mentioned [Nullable.GetValueOrDefault(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d.aspx) is also more correct.

Comment: There are Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault methods for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mails = from m in entity.mailboxes
            join p in entity.ordinary_user_profile_info on m.from_id equals p.user_id
            select new MailList
            {
                mid = m.m_id,
                mfrom = (int)m.from_id,  // Error occours here
                mfomname = p.username,
                msubject = m.subject
            };
```